# Como passar duas variáveis de uma view para o controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5, view, controller

eu tenho um link onde já passo uma variável para o controller. Funciona ok. Como eu faço para passar duas?

Meu link na View:

```
<a href="{{url("/ordemvar/$equipam->codigoequipamento")}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i></a>
```

Seria algo assim?

```
<a href="{{url("/ordemvar/$equipam->id?$equipam->codigoequipamento")}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i></a>
```

Como eu pego no controller

```
public function pegaEquipa($prm)
{
return $prm;
}
```

Valeu

Comment: Já pesquisou sobre Ajax?

Comment: Não. Este método funciona bem. Só não como passar mais de uma.

Comment: Passa os valores que desejar como uma lista, por exemplo: [123,321,145], assim no Backend você só vai precisar capturar essa lista com a função explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer de vários jeitos.

```
<a href="{ {url("/ordemvar/$equipam->codigoequipamento/$equipam->nome") }}"> Link </a>
```

Veja que acima tem dois **slugs** separados por barra.

Então no seu controller ficaria assim:

```
public function pegaEquipa($slug1, $slug2)
{
    echo $slug1;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $slug2;
}
```

---

Ou por **QueryString**.

```
<a href="{ {url("/ordemvar?id=$equipam->codigoequipamento&nome=$equipam->nome") }}"> Link </a>
```

E no controller ficaria assim:

```
public function pegaEquipa(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->get('id');
    echo '<br>';
    echo $request->get('nome');
}
```

Comment: para usar com 2 parametros não esqueça de adicionar o mesmo na rota ::get('nome/{p1}/{p2})`

Comment: Funcuionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly é. Estava esperando ele falar isso depois. Rsrs